# Método delete (Restful)

Tags: java, api, restful

Gostaria de saber como eu faço um método delete que receba uma lista por parâmetros? Digo, ao invés de passar apenas o `ID` do item a ser deletado, eu quero permitir que sejam selecionados `N` itens e removidos todos de uma vez, em uma única requisição.

Como fazer isto de maneira semântica e que atenda os padrões?

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode passar um array de inteiros ou uma lista de inteiros como parâmetro.
Na hora de deletar voce abre uma transaction, percorre o seu array e vai deletando registro por registro, quando terminar, voce faz o commit da transação.

Não conheço java para escrever o código pra voce, mas faço dessa forma em .NET quando preciso de algo parecido...

Comment: Olá André, obrigado pela resposta rápida!

Pode exemplificar como ficaria a URI, neste caso?

Comment: De cara, eu iria fazer da forma com que vc disse. Mas eu queria tentar não quebrar o padrão RESTful, e por isso, recorri ao fórum para procurar saber como fazer isto de maneira semântica e padronizada.

Comment: Sempre que voce está fazendo uma requisição, o legal é enviar os dados via POST, nesse caso, os dados iriam 'ocultos' na requisição e a URI permaneceria a mesma. Os dados seriam transmitidos via JSON nesse caso...

Comment: André, é justamente isto que não posso fazer. kkk

Comment: Veja bem, o REST prega o uso adequado dos métodos HTTP.
Neste caso, eu devo fazer uso do método @DELETE que o protocolo HTTP oferece.

Comment: Desculpe, fnx... Sou na verdade meio que programdor de backend, front apesar de fazer, não é muito meu forte... De uma olhada nessa resposta... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28054515/how-to-send-delete-with-json-to-the-rest-api-using-httpclient